# Update one table where record found in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am really struggling on how to achieve this and hope that someone can help me. I have the existing function and query:

```
public function setStockAndPrice($product_id) {
  $query = $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . DB_PREFIX . 'product SET quantity = 0, price = 0.00 WHERE product_id = ' . (int)$product_id)
}
```

This works, but it sets all products to Zero when I actually want it to only set products to Zero when that product exists in another table.

i.e., in explanatory terms:

```
public function setStockAndPrice($product_id) {
  $query = $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . DB_PREFIX . 'product SET quantity = 0, price = 0.00 WHERE product_id = ' . (int)$product_id AND product_id exists in CustomerProducts)
}
```

I am not au fait with joins, but I am not sure if I even need to use a join here as the query seems more simple than that.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public function setStockAndPrice($product_id) {
  $query = $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . DB_PREFIX . 'product SET quantity = 0, price = 0.00 WHERE product_id = ' . (int)$product_id ." AND product_id =(select DISTINCT(product_id) from CustomerProducts where product_id= $product_id)" )
  }
```

This may work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried executing that but its giving the error - syntax error, unexpected '='. Sorry - any ideas?

Comment: Thank you again, but sorry again -  Whereas the code ran this time, when it got so far it came up with this error:

PHP Notice:  Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row<br />Error No: 1242<br />UPDATE product SET quantity = 0, price = 0.00 WHERE product_id = 4392 AND product_id =(select product_id from CustomerProducts where product_id= 4392) in /home/sites/opencart/dev/system/database/mysql.php on line 49

I am not sure why it returned more than one row but it doesn't matter how many records are in the CustomerProducts table only that it exists. Update it if it exists, don't if it doesn't.

Comment: it is because your second table contains more than one rows for the `$product_id` i have edited again now try that..

Comment: Brilliant it runs with out error.
Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it. Rob

Answer (score 0):

use this will work for you are not assigning `db.product` and make sure you write query in a string then execute.

And you see you query, by removing comments

```
public function setStockAndPrice($product_id) {
  $query_string = "UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . ".product SET quantity = '0', price = '0.00' WHERE product_id = '$product_id'";

  // echo "Query : " . $query_string;

  $query = $this->db->query($query_string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function setStockAndPrice($product_id) {
      $query = $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . DB_PREFIX . '.product p, ' . DB_PREFIX . '.CustomerProducts cp SET p.quantity = 0, p.price = 0.00 WHERE p.product_id = ' . (int)$product_id . ' AND p.product_id = cp.product_id');
    }
```